# I created a custom view by subclassing SearchView. How can I reference in it XML now?

Tags: android, xml, android-view, android-custom-view

I programmatically creating a custom view by extending the AppCompat SearchView. How do I reference this class in my XML? I cannot use the fully qualified name because I am using different product flavors with gradle that have different package names. Specifically, `app:actionViewClass=".views.EventSearchView"` causes a `ClassNotFoundException`

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:orderInCategory="99"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        app:actionViewClass=".views.EventSearchView"
        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Comment: try to use class name with full package name `app:actionViewClass="xxxxx.xxxx.views.EventSearchView"`

Comment: I tried that. But different builds of my app have different package names because of gradle's product flavors/build variants.

How can I fix this?

Comment: show full log which getting when using `app:actionViewClass=".views.EventSearchView"`

Comment: Have you tried to create `MenuItem` programmatically? You can always check the package name at runtime

Comment: not sure what was going on, but it works now. I used the fully qualified package name and everything is fine. I must have had a typo somewhere..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fully Qualified Package Name and the `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` namespace did the trick. I must have had a typo somewhere.